# Sabre Hotel Reservation Not working

Tags: sabre

I have been trying to reserve an hotel with the Sabre Hotel Reservation error and I have getting series of errors ranging from, "NO AVAIL", "FORMAT"

Attached below is a step by step process starting from HotelPropertyDescription to HotelRes

HotelPropertyDescriptionRQ

```
<HotelPropertyDescriptionRQ Version="2.3.0" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <AvailRequestSegment>
        <GuestCounts Count="1" />
        <HotelSearchCriteria>
            <Criterion>
                <HotelRef HotelCode="0037781" />
            </Criterion>
        </HotelSearchCriteria>
        <TimeSpan End="01-31" Start="01-29" />
    </AvailRequestSegment>
</HotelPropertyDescriptionRQ>
```

HotelPropertyDescriptionRS

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap-env:Header><eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1"><eb:From><eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">https://sws-crt.cert.havail.sabre.com</eb:PartyId></eb:From><eb:To><eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">localhost:8000</eb:PartyId></eb:To><eb:CPAId><<--Romved By ME-->></eb:CPAId><eb:ConversationId>convId</eb:ConversationId><eb:Service eb:type="OTA">HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ</eb:Service><eb:Action>HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRS</eb:Action><eb:MessageData><eb:MessageId>1191447481752920151</eb:MessageId><eb:Timestamp>2018-01-11T13:22:56</eb:Timestamp><eb:RefToMessageId>1190841481505850610</eb:RefToMessageId></eb:MessageData></eb:MessageHeader><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext"><wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary"><<--Romved By ME-->></wsse:BinarySecurityToken></wsse:Security></soap-env:Header><soap-env:Body><HotelPropertyDescriptionRS xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" Version="2.3.0">
 <stl:ApplicationResults status="Complete">
  <stl:Success timeStamp="2018-01-11T07:22:56-06:00"/>
 </stl:ApplicationResults>
 <RoomStay>
  <BasicPropertyInfo ChainCode="PR" GeoConfidenceLevel="0" HotelCityCode="JNB" HotelCode="0037781" HotelName="PR BALALAIKA SANDTON" Latitude="-26.106467" Longitude="28.053686" RPH="001">
   <Address>
    <AddressLine>20 MAUDE STREET</AddressLine>
    <AddressLine>SANDTON ZA 2146</AddressLine>
    <CountryCode>ZA</CountryCode>
   </Address>
   <Awards>
    <AwardProvider>NTM3  CROWN</AwardProvider>
   </Awards>
   <CheckInTime>14:00</CheckInTime>
   <CheckOutTime>11:00</CheckOutTime>
   <ContactNumbers>
    <ContactNumber Fax="27-11-322 5021" Phone="27-11-322 5000"/>
   </ContactNumbers>
   <DirectConnect Ind="true">
    <AdditionalData Ind="false"/>
    <CurrencyConverted Ind="false"/>
    <DC_AvailParticipant Ind="true"/>
    <DC_SellParticipant Ind="true"/>
    <RequestFail Ind="false"/>
    <UnAvail Ind="false"/>
   </DirectConnect>
   <IndexData>
    <Index DistanceDirection="10N" LocationCode="A" Point="JNB" TransportationCode="O"/>
   </IndexData>
   <PropertyOptionInfo>
    <ADA_Accessible Ind="false"/>
    <AdultsOnly Ind="false"/>
    <AirportShuttle Ind="false"/>
    <BeachFront Ind="false"/>
    <Breakfast Ind="false"/>
    <BusinessCenter Ind="false"/>
    <BusinessReady Ind="false"/>
    <CarRentalCounter>N</CarRentalCounter>
    <Conventions Ind="false"/>
    <Dataport Ind="false"/>
    <Dining Ind="true"/>
    <DryClean Ind="false"/>
    <EcoCertified Ind="false"/>
    <ExecutiveFloors Ind="false"/>
    <FamilyPlan Ind="false"/>
    <FitnessCenter Ind="false"/>
    <FreeLocalCalls Ind="false"/>
    <FreeParking Ind="false"/>
    <FreeShuttle Ind="false"/>
    <FreeWifiInMeetingRooms Ind="false"/>
    <FreeWifiInPublicSpaces Ind="false"/>
    <FreeWifiInRooms Ind="false"/>
    <FullServiceSpa Ind="false"/>
    <GameFacilities Ind="false"/>
    <Golf Ind="false"/>
    <GovtSafetyFire Ind="false"/>
    <HighSpeedInternet Ind="true"/>
    <HypoallergenicRooms Ind="false"/>
    <IndoorPool Ind="false"/>
    <IndPetRestriction Ind="false"/>
    <InRoomCoffeeTea Ind="false"/>
    <InRoomMiniBar Ind="false"/>
    <InRoomRefrigerator Ind="false"/>
    <InRoomSafe Ind="false"/>
    <InteriorDoorways Ind="false"/>
    <Jacuzzi Ind="false"/>
    <KidsFacilities Ind="false"/>
    <KitchenFacilities Ind="false"/>
    <MealService Ind="true"/>
    <MeetingFacilities Ind="true"/>
    <NoAdultTV Ind="false"/>
    <NonSmoking Ind="false"/>
    <OutdoorPool Ind="false"/>
    <Parking>Y</Parking>
    <Pets Ind="false"/>
    <Pool Ind="true"/>
    <PublicTransportationAdjacent Ind="false"/>
    <Recreation Ind="false"/>
    <RestrictedRoomAccess Ind="false"/>
    <RoomService Ind="true"/>
    <RoomService24Hours Ind="false"/>
    <RoomsWithBalcony Ind="false"/>
    <SkiInOutProperty Ind="false"/>
    <SmokeFree Ind="false"/>
    <SmokingRoomsAvail Ind="false"/>
    <Tennis Ind="false"/>
    <WaterPurificationSystem Ind="false"/>
    <Wheelchair Ind="true"/>
   </PropertyOptionInfo>
   <PropertyTypeInfo>
    <AllInclusive Ind="false"/>
    <Apartments Ind="false"/>
    <BedBreakfast Ind="false"/>
    <Castle Ind="false"/>
    <Conventions Ind="false"/>
    <Economy Ind="false"/>
    <ExtendedStay Ind="false"/>
    <Farm Ind="false"/>
    <First Ind="false"/>
    <Luxury Ind="true"/>
    <Moderate Ind="false"/>
    <Motel Ind="false"/>
    <Resort Ind="false"/>
    <Suites Ind="false"/>
   </PropertyTypeInfo>
   <SpecialOffers Ind="false"/>
   <Taxes>
    <Text>TAX INCL</Text>
    <Text>SVC EXCL</Text>
   </Taxes>
   <VendorMessages>
    <AdditionalAttractions>
     <Text>- NEARBY CORPORATE LOCATIONS INCLUDE:</Text>
     <Text>* JOHANNESBURG CITY CENTRE ... 16KM</Text>
     <Text>* SANDTON CITY ....... 0.2KM</Text>
     <Text>* ABSA PARK .......... 0.1KM</Text>
    </AdditionalAttractions>
    <Cancellation>
     <Text>SHOULD THE RESERVATION BE CANCELLED LESS THAN 24HRS FROM DAY OF</Text>
     <Text>ARRIVAL, A CANCELLATION FEE OF 1 NIGHT S STAY PLUS 1PERCENT</Text>
     <Text>LEVY WILL BE CHARGED</Text>
    </Cancellation>
    <Deposit>
     <Text>THE DEPOSIT IS REQUIRED AT THE TIME OF RESERVATION.</Text>
    </Deposit>
    <Description>
     <Text>FOR THOSE WHO SEEK PREMIER QUALITY AND ELEGANCE, THE PROTEA</Text>
     <Text>HOTEL BALALAIKA IS THE DISTINCTIVELY SUPERIOR CHOICE.</Text>
     <Text>ESTABLISHED IN 1949, THE PROTEA HOTEL BALALAIKA IS A PRIVATELY</Text>
     <Text>OWNED PREMIER HOTEL, SET IN THE HEART OF SANDTON, SOUTH AFRICA.</Text>
    </Description>
    <Dining>
     <Text>*THE COLONY RESTAURANT</Text>
     <Text>THE RESTAURANT IS OPEN FIVE DAYS A WEEK FOR BREAKFAST FROM</Text>
     <Text>06H30 TO 10H00 AND WEEKENDS FROM 07H00 TO 10H30, WHERE A LAVISH</Text>
     <Text>FULL ENGLISH BREAKFAST BUFFET IS SERVED. THE RESTAURANT IS</Text>
     <Text>CLOSED FOR LUNCH AND DINNER. PROKARD GOLD IS ACCEPTED.</Text>
     <Text>*THE BULL RUN RESTAURANT</Text>
     <Text>A WEALTH OF GOOD TASTE.INDULGE YOUR SENSES IN OUR WARM,</Text>
     <Text>SPACIOUS INTERIOR, EMBELLISHED WITH FINE WOOD AND FACE BRICK,</Text>
     <Text>CATERING FOR THE CONNOISSEURS OF CHOICE MEAT AND SELECT WINES.</Text>
     <Text>VISIT OUR IN-HOUSE BUTCHERY FOR FRESH CUTS OF MATURELY AGED</Text>
     <Text>MEAT, CUT AND PACKED FOR YOUR SPECIFIC REQUIREMENTS. A MUST FOR</Text>
     <Text>BOTH LOCAL AND INTERNATIONAL GUESTS ALIKE. ENJOY FRESH OYSTERS,</Text>
     <Text>WHILE SIPPING AN EXOTIC COCKTAIL ON THE TERRACE. OPEN DAILY FOR</Text>
     <Text>LUNCH AND DINNER, MONDAY TO SUNDAY. CLOSED ON SATURDAY FOR</Text>
     <Text>LUNCH. PROKARD GOLD IS ACCEPTED.</Text>
     <Text>*THE OVAL COFFEE SHOP</Text>
     <Text>THE OVAL COFFEE SHOP OFFERS A VARIETY OF LIGHT MEALS SUCH AS</Text>
     <Text>TRAMEZZINI AND CIABATTA WITH NUMEROUS SELECTIONS OF DIFFERENT</Text>
     <Text>FILLINGS. CAKES, PASTRIES AND SPECIALTY COFFEES ARE ALSO</Text>
     <Text>AVAILABLE. OPEN SEVEN DAYS A WEEK FROM 09H00 TO 21H00. IN THE</Text>
     <Text>WINTER MONTHS, ENJOY OUR HOT HOME-MADE SOUP OF THE DAY, SERVED</Text>
     <Text>WITH FRENCH LOAF.</Text>
     <Text>*LORDS CIGAR BAR</Text>
     <Text>A SOPHISTICATED LOUNGE BAR, DECORATED IN LUXURIOUS SOLID WOOD</Text>
     <Text>FURNISHINGS, CHANDELIERS, AND RICH PLUSH UPHOLSTERY. A VAST</Text>
     <Text>VARIETY OF SPECIALTY COCKTAILS ARE AVAILABLE. HOT SAVORIES ARE</Text>
     <Text>SERVED DAILY AT 17H00. INTERNATIONAL CIGARS FROM ALL OVER THE</Text>
     <Text>WORLD ARE IMPORTED. CHOOSE ONE FROM OUR SPECIALLY DESIGNED</Text>
     <Text>CIGAR MENU.</Text>
    </Dining>
    <Directions>
     <Text>- TAKE THE R24 TOWARDS JOHANNESBURG.  TRAVEL FOR 10KM AND</Text>
     <Text>TAKE THE N3 TURNOFF TO PRETORIA.  TAKE THE MARLBORO</Text>
     <Text>DRIVE TURNOFF AND TURN LEFT AT THE TRAFFIC LIGHTS.</Text>
     <Text>CONTINUE UNDER THE BRIDGE INTO GRAYSTON DRIVE.  TURN</Text>
     <Text>LEFT INTO RIVONIA ROAD AND AT THE FIRST SET OF</Text>
     <Text>TRAFFIC LIGHTS TURN INTO MAUDE STREET WHERE THE HOTEL</Text>
     <Text>IS SITUATED ON THE LEFT.</Text>
    </Directions>
    <Facilities>
     <Text>*LOUNGE</Text>
     <Text>*THE POOL TERRACE</Text>
     <Text>*FITNESS CENTRE</Text>
     <Text>*RESTAURANT</Text>
     <Text>*FAX</Text>
     <Text>*PHOTOSTAT COPIES</Text>
     <Text>*BED BOARDS</Text>
     <Text>*EXTRA BEDS</Text>
     <Text>*BABY COTS / HIGH CHAIRS / BABY-SITTING FACILITIES</Text>
     <Text>*MAIL POSTING FACILITIES</Text>
     <Text>*FULL CONCIERGE FACILITIES</Text>
     <Text>*PARKING</Text>
     <Text>*LAUNDRY AND VALET</Text>
     <Text>*EXTRA PILLOWS</Text>
     <Text>*SAFE CUSTODY</Text>
     <Text>*24 HOUR ROOM SERVICE</Text>
     <Text>*PLSE NOTE A CHARGE MAY BE APPLICABLE FOR SOME OF THE ABOVE*</Text>
    </Facilities>
    <Guarantee>
     <Text>ALL RESERVATIONS MUST BE GUARANTEED TO CREDIT CARD AX DC CA VI</Text>
     <Text>IK, TRAVEL AGENT VOUCHER OR DEPOSIT</Text>
    </Guarantee>
    <MiscServices>
     <Text>- PETS ARE NOT ACCEPTED.</Text>
     <Text>- ALL RATES ARE NON COMMISSIONABLE</Text>
    </MiscServices>
    <Recreation>
     <Text>- AVAILABLE CLOSE TO THE HOTEL:</Text>
     <Text>* TENNIS COURTS ..... 2KM</Text>
     <Text>* FITNESS CENTRE .... 1KM</Text>
     <Text>* GOLF COURSE ....... 2KM</Text>
     <Text>*PLSE NOTE A CHARGE MAY BE APPLICABLE FOR SOME OF THE ABOVE*</Text>
    </Recreation>
    <Rooms>
     <Text>ALL ROOMS ARE A DELIGHTFUL REFLECTION OF THE ENGLISH COUNTRY</Text>
     <Text>THEME OF THE HOTEL AND ARE FITTED TO EXCEED THE FOUR STAR</Text>
     <Text>RATING. ALL ROOMS HAVE INDIVIDUALLY CONTROLLED AIR-CONDITIONING</Text>
     <Text>AND HEATING, PRIVATE BATHROOMS WITH SEPARATE SHOWERS, MODEM</Text>
     <Text>POINTS, ADAPTOR POINTS FOR INTERNATIONAL PLUGS, T.V. WITH AN</Text>
     <Text>ADDITIONAL FIVE SATELLITE STATIONS, THREE GERMAN CHANNELS,</Text>
     <Text>M-NET, RADIO, TEA/COFFEE MAKING FACILITIES AND ELECTRONIC</Text>
     <Text>SAFES. MINI-BARS ARE AVAILABLE ON REQUEST. NON-SMOKING ROOMS</Text>
     <Text>ARE AVAILABLE UPON REQUEST.</Text>
    </Rooms>
    <Safety>
     <Text>- THE HOTEL OFFERS 24HOURS ON SITE SECURITY, PORTER</Text>
     <Text>SERVICE AND RECEPTION.  SMOKE DETECTORS ARE INSTALLED IN</Text>
     <Text>ALL ROOMS AND PUBLIC PLACES.</Text>
    </Safety>
    <Services>
     <Text>* ROOM SERVICE      * FOREIGN EXCHANGE      * BABY SITTING</Text>
     <Text>* LAUNDRY              * PORTERS                       * VALET</Text>
     <Text>*PLS NOTE A CHARGE MAY BE APPLICABLE FOR SOME OF THE ABOVE*</Text>
    </Services>
    <Transportation>
     <Text>RECOMMENDED MEANS OF TRANSPORT BETWEEN AIRPORT AND HOTEL IS</Text>
     <Text>EITHER BY AIRPORT SHUTTLE CHARGED  OR PRIVATE TAXI.</Text>
    </Transportation>
   </VendorMessages>
  </BasicPropertyInfo>
  <Guarantee>
   <GuaranteesAccepted>
    <PaymentCard Code="AX" Type="AMERICAN EXPRESS"/>
    <PaymentCard Code="CA" Type="MASTERCARD"/>
    <PaymentCard Code="DC" Type="DINERS CLUB CARD"/>
    <PaymentCard Code="DS" Type="DISCOVER CARD"/>
    <PaymentCard Code="IK" Type="MASTER CARD"/>
    <PaymentCard Code="MC" Type="MASTER CARD"/>
    <PaymentCard Code="VI" Type="VISA"/>
   </GuaranteesAccepted>
  </Guarantee>
  <RoomRates>
   <RoomRate DirectConnect="false" GuaranteeSurchargeRequired="D" GuaranteedRateProgram="false" IATA_CharacteristicIdentification="APND00" IATA_ProductIdentification="ADVANCE PURCHASE" LowInventoryThreshold="false" RPH="001" RateChangeInd="false" RateConversionInd="false" SpecialOffer="false">
    <AdditionalInfo>
     <CancelPolicy Numeric="00" Option="N">
      <Text>UP TO 01 DAYS AFTER BOOKING</Text>
     </CancelPolicy>
     <Commission NonCommission="false">COMMISSIONABLE</Commission>
     <Text>ADVANCE PURCHASE RATE, INCLUDES PREPAY IN FULL, NON-REFUNDABLE,</Text>
     <Text>NO CHANGES, STANDARD, GUEST ROOM, 1 KING</Text>
    </AdditionalInfo>
    <Rates>
     <Rate Amount="1912.50" ChangeIndicator="false" CurrencyCode="ZAR" HRD_RequiredForSell="true" PackageIndicator="false" RateConversionInd="false" ReturnOfRateInd="false" RoomOnRequest="false">
      <AdditionalGuestAmounts>
       <AdditionalGuestAmount MaxExtraPersonsAllowed="0">
        <Charges ExtraPerson="0"/>
       </AdditionalGuestAmount>
      </AdditionalGuestAmounts>
      <HotelTotalPricing Amount="3863.25">
       <Disclaimer>INCLUDES TAXES AND SURCHARGES</Disclaimer>
       <TotalTaxes Amount="38.25"/>
      </HotelTotalPricing>
     </Rate>
    </Rates>
   </RoomRate>
   <RoomRate DirectConnect="false" GuaranteeSurchargeRequired="G" GuaranteedRateProgram="false" IATA_CharacteristicIdentification="REGA00" IATA_ProductIdentification="REGULAR RATE" LowInventoryThreshold="false" RPH="002" RateChangeInd="false" RateConversionInd="false" SpecialOffer="false">
    <AdditionalInfo>
     <CancelPolicy Numeric="06" Option="P"/>
     <Commission NonCommission="false">COMMISSIONABLE</Commission>
     <Text>BEST AVAILABLE RATE REGULAR RATE,, SEE RATE RULES, STANDARD,</Text>
     <Text>GUEST ROOM, 1 KING</Text>
    </AdditionalInfo>
    <Rates>
     <Rate Amount="2250.00" ChangeIndicator="false" CurrencyCode="ZAR" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" PackageIndicator="false" RateConversionInd="false" ReturnOfRateInd="false" RoomOnRequest="false">
      <AdditionalGuestAmounts>
       <AdditionalGuestAmount MaxExtraPersonsAllowed="0">
        <Charges ExtraPerson="0"/>
       </AdditionalGuestAmount>
      </AdditionalGuestAmounts>
      <HotelTotalPricing Amount="4545.00">
       <Disclaimer>INCLUDES TAXES AND SURCHARGES</Disclaimer>
       <TotalTaxes Amount="45.00"/>
      </HotelTotalPricing>
     </Rate>
    </Rates>
   </RoomRate>
   <RoomRate DirectConnect="false" GuaranteeSurchargeRequired="D" GuaranteedRateProgram="false" IATA_CharacteristicIdentification="APNN00" IATA_ProductIdentification="ADVANCE PURCHASE" LowInventoryThreshold="false" RPH="003" RateChangeInd="false" RateConversionInd="false" SpecialOffer="false">
    <AdditionalInfo>
     <CancelPolicy Numeric="00" Option="N">
      <Text>UP TO 01 DAYS AFTER BOOKING</Text>
     </CancelPolicy>
     <Commission NonCommission="false">COMMISSIONABLE</Commission>
     <Text>ADVANCE PURCHASE RATE, INCLUDES PREPAY IN FULL, NON-REFUNDABLE,</Text>
     <Text>NO CHANGES, 2 BEDROOM SUITE</Text>
    </AdditionalInfo>
    <Rates>
     <Rate Amount="2762.50" ChangeIndicator="false" CurrencyCode="ZAR" HRD_RequiredForSell="true" PackageIndicator="false" RateConversionInd="false" ReturnOfRateInd="false" RoomOnRequest="false">
      <AdditionalGuestAmounts>
       <AdditionalGuestAmount MaxExtraPersonsAllowed="0">
        <Charges ExtraPerson="0"/>
       </AdditionalGuestAmount>
      </AdditionalGuestAmounts>
      <HotelTotalPricing Amount="5580.25">
       <Disclaimer>INCLUDES TAXES AND SURCHARGES</Disclaimer>
       <TotalTaxes Amount="55.25"/>
      </HotelTotalPricing>
     </Rate>
    </Rates>
   </RoomRate>
   <RoomRate DirectConnect="false" GuaranteeSurchargeRequired="D" GuaranteedRateProgram="false" IATA_CharacteristicIdentification="APNM00" IATA_ProductIdentification="ADVANCE PURCHASE" LowInventoryThreshold="false" RPH="004" RateChangeInd="false" RateConversionInd="false" SpecialOffer="false">
    <AdditionalInfo>
     <CancelPolicy Numeric="00" Option="N">
      <Text>UP TO 01 DAYS AFTER BOOKING</Text>
     </CancelPolicy>
     <Commission NonCommission="false">COMMISSIONABLE</Commission>
     <Text>ADVANCE PURCHASE RATE, INCLUDES PREPAY IN FULL, NON-REFUNDABLE,</Text>
     <Text>NO CHANGES, SUITE, 1 KING</Text>
    </AdditionalInfo>
    <Rates>
     <Rate Amount="2762.50" ChangeIndicator="false" CurrencyCode="ZAR" HRD_RequiredForSell="true" PackageIndicator="false" RateConversionInd="false" ReturnOfRateInd="false" RoomOnRequest="false">
      <AdditionalGuestAmounts>
       <AdditionalGuestAmount MaxExtraPersonsAllowed="0">
        <Charges ExtraPerson="0"/>
       </AdditionalGuestAmount>
      </AdditionalGuestAmounts>
      <HotelTotalPricing Amount="5580.25">
       <Disclaimer>INCLUDES TAXES AND SURCHARGES</Disclaimer>
       <TotalTaxes Amount="55.25"/>
      </HotelTotalPricing>
     </Rate>
    </Rates>
   </RoomRate>
   <RoomRate DirectConnect="false" GuaranteeSurchargeRequired="G" GuaranteedRateProgram="false" IATA_CharacteristicIdentification="REGD00" IATA_ProductIdentification="REGULAR RATE" LowInventoryThreshold="false" RPH="005" RateChangeInd="false" RateConversionInd="false" SpecialOffer="false">
    <AdditionalInfo>
     <CancelPolicy Numeric="06" Option="P"/>
     <Commission NonCommission="false">COMMISSIONABLE</Commission>
     <Text>BEST AVAILABLE RATE REGULAR RATE,, SEE RATE RULES, 2 BEDROOM</Text>
     <Text>SUITE</Text>
    </AdditionalInfo>
    <Rates>
     <Rate Amount="3250.00" ChangeIndicator="false" CurrencyCode="ZAR" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" PackageIndicator="false" RateConversionInd="false" ReturnOfRateInd="false" RoomOnRequest="false">
      <AdditionalGuestAmounts>
       <AdditionalGuestAmount MaxExtraPersonsAllowed="0">
        <Charges ExtraPerson="0"/>
       </AdditionalGuestAmount>
      </AdditionalGuestAmounts>
      <HotelTotalPricing Amount="6565.00">
       <Disclaimer>INCLUDES TAXES AND SURCHARGES</Disclaimer>
       <TotalTaxes Amount="65.00"/>
      </HotelTotalPricing>
     </Rate>
    </Rates>
   </RoomRate>
   <RoomRate DirectConnect="false" GuaranteeSurchargeRequired="G" GuaranteedRateProgram="false" IATA_CharacteristicIdentification="REGC00" IATA_ProductIdentification="REGULAR RATE" LowInventoryThreshold="false" RPH="006" RateChangeInd="false" RateConversionInd="false" SpecialOffer="false">
    <AdditionalInfo>
     <CancelPolicy Numeric="06" Option="P"/>
     <Commission NonCommission="false">COMMISSIONABLE</Commission>
     <Text>BEST AVAILABLE RATE REGULAR RATE,, SEE RATE RULES, SUITE, 1</Text>
     <Text>KING</Text>
    </AdditionalInfo>
    <Rates>
     <Rate Amount="3250.00" ChangeIndicator="false" CurrencyCode="ZAR" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" PackageIndicator="false" RateConversionInd="false" ReturnOfRateInd="false" RoomOnRequest="false">
      <AdditionalGuestAmounts>
       <AdditionalGuestAmount MaxExtraPersonsAllowed="0">
        <Charges ExtraPerson="0"/>
       </AdditionalGuestAmount>
      </AdditionalGuestAmounts>
      <HotelTotalPricing Amount="6565.00">
       <Disclaimer>INCLUDES TAXES AND SURCHARGES</Disclaimer>
       <TotalTaxes Amount="65.00"/>
      </HotelTotalPricing>
     </Rate>
    </Rates>
   </RoomRate>
  </RoomRates>
  <TimeSpan Duration="0005" End="2018-01-31" Start="2018-01-29"/>
 </RoomStay>
</HotelPropertyDescriptionRS></soap-env:Body></soap-env:Envelope>
```

HotelResRQ

```
<OTA_HotelResRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ReturnHostCommand="false" TimeStamp="2013-11-22T17:15:00-06:00" Version="2.2.0">
                <Hotel>
                  <BasicPropertyInfo RPH="001" />
                  <Customer NameNumber="1.1" />           
                  <Guarantee Type="D">
                    <CC_Info>
                     <PaymentCard Code="VI" ExpireDate="2019-07" Number="4111111111111111"/>
                     <PersonName>
                     <Surname>TESTING</Surname>
                     </PersonName>
                    </CC_Info>
                  </Guarantee>
                  <RoomType NumberOfUnits="1"/>
                  <SpecialPrefs>
                   <WrittenConfirmation Ind="true" />
                  </SpecialPrefs>
                </Hotel>
              </OTA_HotelResRQ>
```

HotelResRS

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap-env:Header><eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1"><eb:From><eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">https://sws-crt.cert.havail.sabre.com</eb:PartyId></eb:From><eb:To><eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">localhost:8000</eb:PartyId></eb:To><eb:CPAId><<--Romved By ME-->></eb:CPAId><eb:ConversationId>convId</eb:ConversationId><eb:Service eb:type="OTA">OTA_HotelResLLSRQ</eb:Service><eb:Action>OTA_HotelResLLSRS</eb:Action><eb:MessageData><eb:MessageId>1192612482294130151</eb:MessageId><eb:Timestamp>2018-01-11T13:23:50</eb:Timestamp><eb:RefToMessageId>1192430482217330150</eb:RefToMessageId></eb:MessageData></eb:MessageHeader><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext"><wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary"><<--Romved By ME-->></wsse:BinarySecurityToken></wsse:Security></soap-env:Header><soap-env:Body><OTA_HotelResRS xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" Version="2.2.0">
 <stl:ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed">
  <stl:Error type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2018-01-11T07:23:50-06:00">
   <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
    <stl:Message code="0">FORMAT</stl:Message>
    <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</stl:ShortText>
   </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
  </stl:Error>
 </stl:ApplicationResults>
</OTA_HotelResRS></soap-env:Body></soap-env:Envelope>
```

It returned 'FORMAT' as the error this time, sometimes it returns 'NO AVAIL'.

I followed the steps as provided on the Sabre Dev studio but I still feel I am doing something wrong.
Any way I can solve this ?

Answer (score 2):

For deposit you should be using GuaranteeType as "GDPST".

"Type" can be "G", "GAGT", "GDPST", "GC", "GCR", "GH", "GDPSTH", "GT", or "GDPSTT"

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/hotel/book/book_hotel_reservation/

You should also display the rules before attempting to sell that rate since HRD_RequiredForSell was returned as 'true'.

Comment: Thanks man. I am not running the Hotel rate description, probably why its not going. I ll try it now and get back to you.

Comment: After running the request for some time now, I only get hotels with HRD_RequiredForSell="false". On proceeding to the hotel reservation, i keep getting the same error as above usin 'G' as Guarantee Type

Comment: That particular rate asked for a deposit, so you should use GDPST instead of G.